# Why does my infant bang her head sideways in sleep?

Tags: infant, sleep, newborn

Age 2.5 months.

I swaddle her and put her in my lap. When she's asleep I notice her banging her head sideways.
Also, today I tried Kangaroo Care and put her naked on my chest (on her stomach), when she was asleep I found her banging her head on my chest.

What could cause this?

Comment: See: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/7187/2146